# Inserting function inside other function in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i have small application written in tkinter, python. I would like  to choose txt file by clicking button in tkinter and automaticaly send it to my SQL database.
For this moment i have function responsible for choosing a file from my disc and printing my txt file in console:

```
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="",
                       filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")),
                       title = "Choose a file."
                       )
    print(name)
    #Using try in case user types in unknown file or closes without choosing a file.
    try:
        with open(name,'r') as UseFile:
            print(UseFile.read())
    except:
        print("No file exists")
```

And function responsible for sending to SQL looks this way (txt file is inserted inside function):

```
def Tabela():
    with open("pom1.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            data = line.split("\t")
            print(data)
            query = ("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES"
                 "(" + data[1] + ", " + data[2] + ", " + data[3] + ");")
            cursor.execute(query, data)
            con.commit()
   return
```

Does anybody knows what could i do to connect those two functions? The idea is to choose txt file from function OpenFile() and then application should send it automatically to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Tabela` take the file as a parameter instead of hard-coding `pom1.txt`, and call `Tabela(UseFile)` from `OpenFile()`.

Also, since you're calling `cursor.execute()` with parameters, you shouldn't concatenate the elements of `data` into `query`, just put placeholders in the query.

```
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="",
                       filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")),
                       title = "Choose a file."
                       )
    print(name)
    #Using try in case user types in unknown file or closes without choosing a file.
    try:
        with open(name,'r') as UseFile:
            Tabela(UseFile)
    except:
        print("No file exists")


def Tabela(infile):
    for line in infile:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        print(data)
        query = ("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
        cursor.execute(query, data)
        con.commit()
   return
```